# How to get stacked doughnut chart using React Highcharts without using "highcharts-react-official" library?

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I want to achieve a stacked donut chart using React Highcharts, which looks something like the attached picture.
[image]

The 84% here resembles, the average of the number of the doughnuts in the stacked doughnut chart. I tried doing a single doughnut first, as I am new to Highcharts. But I used react-highcharts-official library, which I shouldn't use. I am attaching the code for that via stackblitz. please help me how to get this stacked doughnut using Highcharts React.

Thanks in advance.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-d7dzr4?file=index.js (single doughnut chart)

Comment: Hi @pranathi tammina, Why don't you like to use the `highcharts-react-official` wrapper? Here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-gmrx7d you can find a simple example of a doughnut chart in React.

Comment: Thanks for the example, [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-d7dzr4?file=index.js) , I too made a POC regarding single doughnut chart, but I need stacked doughnut and I am not aware of making it. And coming to your question, it's my requirement. If you could help me, please don't mind about highcharts-react-official library,  please provide me some POC which shows gives me an understanding of stacked doughnut as I attached. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a pie chart, you can use a radial bar chart with two series and disable grouping.

```
  chart: {
    polar: true,
    inverted: true,
    ...
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3whcj902/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/radial-bar-chart